# What is the difference between 'Just not' and 'Not just'? Please explain with examples

Tags: word-choice, difference, sentence-choice

Poverty is **......** (just not/not just) a lack of income and the inability to purchase, it is a deeply-rooted multifaceted complex structure comprising economic, social, demographic, cultural, political, and psychological factors.

Comment: ***Just*** has a range of meanings, some of which are quite contradictory. In *That's just what I needed* it's an intensifier meaning ***definitely / exactly / very much / completely***, and that's how it works in *Poverty is just unacceptable to me*. But in *He just wanted to help* it's an "attenuator" (with "weakening" effect) meaning ***merely / only / simply***. That's how it works in "dismissive" *Poverty is just the unacceptable face of capitalism* (it's a trivial side-effect, hardly worth bothering about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Just not' means 'emphatically not'.

> Kicking the dog is just not right!
>
> Marks of three out of ten are just not good enough!'

'Not just' means 'not only', 'not merely', 'not only'.

> My mother is not just a writer; she is also a racing driver and stunt
> pilot.
>
> My smartphone is not just for making voice calls. It is also useful
> for playing games, watching videos, listening to music or the radio,
> and surfing the web.

[Just (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just)

Comment: "Marks of three out of ten are just not good enough, you deserve punishment for that." and "Marks of three out of ten are not just good enough, you deserve an accolade for that."  :)

Answer (score 0):

> I won't answer your question, **not just** because it confuses me, but
> because it gives me headaches.
>
> I love learning languages, **not just** English.
>
> Although I do like to answer most of the questions, **just not** this one.
>
> It's **just not** how it should be.
>
> I answer questions, **not just** this one.
>
> I answer questions, **just not** this one.

All of the above sentences are grammatically correct.

It's usages probably are:

"Not just" with a reason

"Not just" with a noun

"Just not" with [something like an object or a subject]

Because there is a reason in there, that would be **"not just"**